# Is it good to join on different tables depending on discrimination column?

Tags: mysql, eav, entity

I want to build a MySQL database with different trading card, all belonging to different games. Each card, depending on the game, has several properties. For example :

- A *Magic: The Gathering* card has a `power` and a `toughness` (a nullable integer)
- A *Pokemon* card has a `retreat_cost` (a nullable positive integer)

And so on and so forth (not all of those properties are scalar, they could be basically any type).

My first thought was this fiddle : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ew1cYbBABSCKrFMjD9qkJi/2

Of course, it basically works. I can find cards with their own properties, and I guess >I could map them to objects in my project using `cards.id_game` as a discriminator column, but I also see the following problem and wonder if I can do better :

- I can't use any foreign key on `cards.id_metadata` because it could be an ID of any metadata table.

Does anyone have another way to build this that could be "better" ?

Appendix : The fiddle SQL in case the link dies :

```sql
create table cards (
  id int primary key auto_increment,
  id_game int not null,
  id_metadata int not null
);

create table games (
  id int primary key auto_increment,
  name varchar(180) not null
);

create table mtg_metadata (
  id int primary key auto_increment,
  name varchar(180) not null,
  power int default null,
  toughness int default null
);

create table pokemon_metadata (
  id int primary key auto_increment,
  name varchar(180) not null,
  hp int default null,
  retreat_cost int default null
);

alter table cards
    add constraint cards_fk_game
        foreign key (id_game) references games (id);
        
insert into games (name) values ('Pokemon');
insert into games (name) values ('Magic: The Gathering');

insert into mtg_metadata(name, power, toughness) values ('Grizzly Bears', 2, 2);
insert into pokemon_metadata(name, hp, retreat_cost) values ('Pikachu', 60, 1);

insert into cards(id_game, id_metadata) values (2, 1);
insert into cards(id_game, id_metadata) values (1, 1);
```

Comment: That's over-normalized.  It's an Entity-Attribute-Value schema design, about which is written.

Comment: It's actually not Entity-Attribute-Value. It's Polymorphic Associations. I have written about that [a bunch on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A20860+%5Bpolymorphic-associations%5D), and in a chapter of my book, [SQL Antipatterns, Volume 1](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksap1/sql-antipatterns-volume-1/).

Comment: Is this design really used ? It seems to basically defeat the point of having an RDBMS, doesn't it ?

Comment: @BillKarwin *Each card, depending on the game, has several properties* - this is clear EAV. An entity is `(card, game)`. Combining to the groups of specific properties stored in separate tables makes it PA.

Comment: @Akina, Each card type has its own table with its attributes defined in individual columns. `power`, `toughness`, `hp`, `retreat_cost`, etc. If it were EAV, there would be one table for all card types, and just two more columns for the attribute name and the attribute value. Don't get me wrong, this is still a problematic design. But it's not EAV.

Comment: @BillKarwin *Each card type has its own table with its attributes defined in individual columns.* True. OP realizes PA whereas he would use EAV.